# select_db in mysql.connector?

Tags: mysql, mysql-connector-python

I created a database

```
import mysql.connector as mysql
create_database = "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS " + self.database
```

and I want to select the database after creating it

```
 self.db = mysql.connect(
        host=self.host,
        port=self.port,
        user=self.user,
        passwd=self.passwd,

    )

    cursor = self.db.cursor()
    cursor.execute(create_database)
    self.db.select_db(self.database)
```

And comes the error :AttributeError: 'CMySQLConnection' object has no attribute 'select_db'

Can't find any answer about this using mysql.connector.

What is the exact way to select a database and make it in session?
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `database` (or the alias `db`) option in `connect()` if you already have a database.

In your case that you want to create and use it afterwards, you can use `self.db.cmd_init_db(self.database)`.

Just keep in mind that you need to get another cursor, the one used to create the database doesn't have a default database.